# Prove if $(a,b)>(c,d)$ and k$\not=0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

In my class we had developed the integers and defined $(a,b)>(c,d)$ iff $a + d > b + c$.

I now need to prove the following but have no real idea on how to do so any help would be appreciated:

Prove if $(a,b)>(c,d)$ and k$\not=0$ then $(a,b)(0,k)<(c,d)(0,k)$.

Comment: If you meant $(a,b)(x,y)$ then we defined it as $(ax+by, ay+bx)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition,

$$(a,b)(0,k) = (a\cdot0+b\cdot k,a\cdot k + b\cdot0)=(kb,ka)$$

And

$$(c,d)(0,k) = (kd,kc)$$

If $(a,b)>(c,d)$, then $a+d > b+c$. Multiplying this by $k$ (a natural number and therefore $>0$) gives $ka + kd > kb + kc$. Using commutativity gives $kd + ka > kc + kb$. Thus by the definition of $>$, we have $(kd,kc)>(kb,ka)$ so $(a,b)(0,k) < (c,d)(0,k)$.